# Timer in windows service

Tags: .net

I have an issue with System.Threading.Timer. I am scheduling some actions using a time in a windows service. The timer starts executing the callback after a specified dueTime period. The windows service starts up after reboot automatically. However, I have observed a strange thing after a system reboot- the callback method starts executing itself 3 or 4 minutes before the specified period. What might be the reason for such behavior?

Here is the sample code:

```
TimeSpan timeToWait = this.StartTime - DateTime.Now;
Int64 msToSleep = (Int64)Math.Round(timeToWait.TotalMilliseconds);
_timer = new Timer(callback_method, null, msToSleep, MinutesScheduledInterval * 60000);
```

where _timer is a member variable, StartTime - the time when the timer should first fire.

Comment: Have you tried logging the values of all the variables involved in this code?

Comment: Yep, sure. The values involved here are those expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How soon after boot does your service start?  The Windows Time service can adjust the clock to get it in sync with a domain controller.  Your DateTime.Now value might be taken before that happens.  Diagnose this first by entering the BIOS at boot-up and checking the clock.  Fix it with a service dependency.

Comment: What do you mean by service dependency? Look, I am doing this on a remote server, and do not have the posibility to do as you suggested.

Comment: Dependencies tab of the service properties.  If you can't reach the keyboard then surely the local admin can?

Comment: Could you please give me an example of service on which the current service might be dependant on? Is the Net Logon service appropriate here?

Comment: I don't know enough about your service.  But I'd try Windows Time first.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thank you for your effort.